# Can I prestore data using drift flutter for web development

Tags: database, flutter, web-development-server, drift

I am trying to store the data in database before running the application instead of writing the database into the application itself for web development of flutter using drift. Is this possible? If so can you provide me with a way on how to do that(maybe SQLite somehow)? If not is there an alternative? or will I have to use an online database such as firebase?

I tried to find anything on the matter, but it is either that is very scarce material on the matter, or I am not understanding how their accessing their databases in their tutorials.